# onAppear not updating instantly in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two views: the list, and the detail.

When I tap into the list item and access the detail view, I can configure settings to that model item.

If I have it update (save to CoreData) `.onDisappear` the List View's `.onAppear` doesn't trigger with the new saved data.

However, if I add in a "save" button in the Detail View and then manually unwind to the List View the data updates instantly.

Is there a reason for `.onDisappear` and `.onAppear` for different screens not triggering in order?

I would have thought that the unwind of the DetailView would trigger the function before the ListView's onAppear would, unless I'm missing something?

I tried to find some info about running them synchronously but with the new async the results haven't been clear.

> **Note:** I'm not displaying the CoreDataManager but it essentially has 4 functions - `create(...all the variables to save...)`, `retrieve()`, `update()`, `delete()`

### Example code

#### ListView

```swift
struct ListView: View {
 let coreDM = CoreDataManager()
 @State var days: [Int] = []
 var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
   List(0..<5) { item in
    NavigationLink {
     DetailView()
    } label: {
     Text("List item: \(item)")
    }
   }
  }.onAppear { coreDM.retrieve() }
 }
}
```

#### DetailView

> This version doesn't work

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
 let coreDM = CoreDataManager()
 @State var isOn: Bool = false
 var body: some View {
  Form {
   Toggle("Turn this on", isOn: $isOn)
  }
  .onDisappear { coreDM.update() }
 }
}
```

> This version does work

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
 let coreDM = CoreDataManager()
 @State var isOn: Bool = false
 var body: some View {
  Form {
   Toggle("Turn this on", isOn: $isOn)
  }
  .toolbar {
   ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
    Button {
     coreDM.update()
    } label: {
     Text("Save")
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The reason I am confused is that if I add this portion to the DetailView the update does work correctly:

```swift
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

...
 Button {
  coreDM.update()
  presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
 } label: {
...
```

So it seems that I can unwind the view, update the database, and refresh in one move. But if I want to "automate" it by doing it only on the unwind, the triggers don't work correctly.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do but if your goal is to make sure `onAppear` is called every time the `ListView` is visible, then you can move the `onAppear` modifier to the `List`.

Comment: @Anwuna its more that the `.onAppear` does get called but before the `.onDisappear` has completed creating inaccurate call results